# Why does object.property not work, when object.property.toString() does when binding?

Tags: reactjs

I'm a total React beginner.

This works, where I reference opportunity.title.toString() (which seems redundant):

```
function BindOpportunities(opportunities) {
    const listItems = opportunities.map((opportunity) =>
       <li key="{opportunity.opportunityId}">{opportunity.title.toString()}</li>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
        document.getElementById('opportunity-list-view')
    );
}
```

And produces the output:

```
<li>Help Us Spread The Work About www.ImmuneAndReadyToHelp.com!</li>
```

...where the object looks like:

```
{"opportunityId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000","title":"Help Us Spread The Work About ImmuneAndReadyToHelp.com!"}
```

However, this does NOT work where I use "property" without .toString(). Can anyone help me understand why?

```
function BindOpportunities(opportunities) {
    const listItems = opportunities.map((opportunity) =>
       <li key="{opportunity.opportunityId}">{opportunity.title}</li>
    );

    ReactDOM.render(
        <ul>{listItems}</ul>,
        document.getElementById('opportunity-list-view')
    );
}
```

NOTE: in response to a comment, I get the warning:

> react-dom.development.js:82 Warning: Encountered two children with the same key, `{opportunity.opportunityId}`. Keys should be unique so that components maintain their identity across updates. Non-unique keys may cause children to be duplicated and/or omitted — the behavior is unsupported and could change in a future version.

Comment: can you share one object from `opportunities`?

Comment: The correct syntax for the key would be ```key={opportunity.opportunityId}``` without any quotes

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz, I added that detail.

Comment: @sarthak-aggarwal, I added that detail.

Comment: what errors do you get without the ```.toString()```?

Comment: Why do you need to use `ReactDOM.render()` in child component?

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz - I'm currently following "Hello World" examples from the React.js parent site, as this is my first experience with the library. If there's an easier way to do it, please let me know!

Comment: @Colin a much safer way would be to call ```ReactDOM.render(<BindOpportunities/>,document.getElementById('opportunity-list-view')``` outside of the component and just use a ```return (<ul>{listItems}</ul>)``` inside

Answer (score 1):

First thing, don't use `ReactDOM.render()` inside a child node, you just need this for root node like `<App />` and then children nodes/components just need to return the jsx in function components and return from render method in case of class base components

```js
function BindOpportunities({ opportunities }) {
    return (
       <ul id="opportunity-list-view">
       { opportunities.map((opportunity) =>
       <li key={opportunity.opportunityId}>{opportunity.title}</li>
    )}
    </ul>
    );
}

const opportunities = [
  {
     "opportunityId":"00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000",
     "title":"Help Us Spread The Work About ImmuneAndReadyToHelp.com!"
  }
];

function App () {
   return (
     <BindOpportunities opportunities={opportunities} />
   );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

Comment: Thanks, though can you please explain why I'd use: document.getElementById('root') instead of document.getElementById('opportunity-list-view')? It seems like there's an extra element in there that I'd prefer not to have.

Comment: I don't know what's your scenario or if you are doing some assignment and you might need exactly that kind of code but in most cases, react app has a one parent root dom element `<div id="root"></div>` with usually id as `root` so that's why I chose `ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));`. It will depend on where you want to mount your whole app, what is id of your root node in index.html

Comment: That arrangement massively blows up with an ambiguous error message in my real-world example. Is there a way to simplify the answer such that if I have a <div id="A"/> and an array const B = [{ "num": "1"}, {"num": "2"}]; I can add div children to "A" based on the data "B"?